# Do we know when $R^if_*\omega_{Y}$ is k-th syzygy sheaf?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $f:Y\rightarrow X$ proper surjective morphism between smooth projective varieties. If $f$ is smooth outside a simple normal crossing divisor, we know that $R^if_*\omega_Y$ is locally free.[Kollár, Higher Direct Images of Dualizing Sheaves II]. We also know by J. Kollár's Higher Direct Images of Dualizing Sheaves I,that when $f$ is just a proper surjective mophism $R^if_*\omega_Y$ is torsion free or 1st syzygy sheaf.

Can we say something similar when $f$ is branched over something of bigger codimension? Do we know any case when $R^if_*\omega_Y$ is $k$-th syzygy sheaf?

Definition of a k-th syzygy sheaf can be found in Notes for the Istanbul Lectures by
Mihnea Popa.

Comment: There are cases when you know such higher direct images are locally free when $f$ is flat and the fibers have *nice* singularities, is that good enough for you?  Sorry, I don't remember the definition of a $k$th syzygy sheaf (Maybe you can provide a link to the actual definition?)

Comment: That is definitely a very useful piece of information that I was not aware of. Could you please give me a reference for the statement you mentioned? Here is the [link](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~mpopa/lectures/istanbul.pdf) to the definition of k-th syzygy sheaf. 
Definition 5.2.

Comment: See for instance section 7 of http://arxiv.org/pdf/0902.0648.pdf  I guess they are assuming also twisting $\omega_Y$ by high powers of relatively ample line bundles, so that probably is non-optimal for you...  The case where that's not needed is if you have a family of Calabi-Yaus (see the above reference).